# Postgresql return table with default value

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to create a function which returns with a table, but I would like to add default values to the values, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cleanDatabase()
RETURNS TABLE 
(
error TEXT,
createConnection TEXT,
dropDatabases TEXT DEFAULT 'OK',
dropTableSpaces TEXT,
closeConnection TEXT
)
AS $$
...
```

But I get the following error:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"

I use default keyword often when I create new tables and it is working fine. 
Is it just not a use case what I am doing here, and I should just create a temporary table with defaults and return with that one?

Comment: you can add coalesce in the select statement where you are returning the data

Answer (score 2):

It doesn’t make sense to have a default for the return type’s columns, because you’re returning every column.

The default value for a table only kicks in when a row is inserted without providing values (as distinct from specifying a null) for columns with default values. There’s no way in PL/SQL to not return all values.

Use `coalesce()` or similar to provide a value when one can’t be determined from your SP logic.